Does an Independent Movement Interior/Exterior Door Lever Exist?
We had a door in a child care room get locked with the interior child latch engaged and the door couldn't be opened from the outside.
Is there a door lever where the levers can move independent of one another to open the door? E.g. this inside is being held still and the outside can still pull the latch to open the door?
Here is the lever that got stuck.


such a handle does exist ... I've seen one where both move, but one is disengaged ... it is unclear how it is useful to know that such a thing exists

Your best bet at finding such a latch, if your google-fu is failing, is to go to a standalone lock and door knob store, usually associated with a locksmith, and ask them. Field-specific stores can often find more unusual items than the big box stores.

Maybe having what stops the door from opening be on the outside.  Even a small hook and eye on the outside will stop the door opening, but be fast to undo.

this is off topic (because this is a commercial space, not your home) but yes a locksmith will know what is available, and will hopefully also be familiar with the fire safety regulations.

why do you need a handle on both sides of this low gate, can't you just reach over?
